# PostGres - How to return null date in query

Tags: postgresql

I have the following function definition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION accounting.func_getData(inputBusinessId bigint, injectionId bigint, inputEndDate DATE) RETURNS TABLE (
    categoryName TEXT,
    amount DECIMAL,
    startDate DATE,
    endDate DATE
    ) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$

BEGIN RETURN QUERY(
   SELECT 'foo', <some value> AS amount, CAST(NULL AS DATE), inputEndDate
   UNION
   ...
)
```

Originally I had 4 input params, one being a date that is always null, so we removed it and added ***CAST(NULL AS DATE)***, which works but seems to be noticeably slower, I can't change the returned columns because we have a common object that requires all fields used in multiple places, is there a way to fix this? Returning NULL does not seem to work here.

Comment: Casting costs about half a microsecond, that in itself can’t be the issue. However, you didn’t share the rest of the code